# Errors were encountered while processing: google-webdesigner

Tags: dpkg

I am trying to install https://www.google.com/webdesigner/

I am getting following error

```
> sudo dpkg -i google-webdesigner_current_amd64.deb 
[sudo] password for baldor: 
Selecting previously unselected package google-webdesigner.
(Reading database ... 220774 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking google-webdesigner (from google-webdesigner_current_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-webdesigner:
 google-webdesigner depends on libc6 (>= 2.17); however:
  Version of libc6 on system is 2.15-0ubuntu10.13.
 google-webdesigner depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.35.9); however:
  Version of libglib2.0-0 on system is 2.32.4-0ubuntu1.
 google-webdesigner depends on lsb-base (>= 4.1); however:
  Version of lsb-base on system is 4.0-0ubuntu20.2.
dpkg: error processing google-webdesigner (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-webdesigner
```

Ubuntu version: 12.04.1

Comment: The first thing I would try on dependency errors is `sudo apt-get install -f` then `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. You can also try changing the download mirror then retrying the commands.

Comment: If not @Parto idea works, you might have to upgrade your Ubuntu version to a newer one. 12.04 is rather old.14.04 is the next LTS version you can upgrade to and 16.04 is the newest.